# java.sql.SQLException: Bad connection URL while accessing the database

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am configuring the database details in one of my spring configuration files as below:

```
<bean id="awd" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:db2://123.43.133.257/XYZ" />
        <property name="username" value="xyz" />
        <property name="password" value="xyz" />
    </bean>
```

When I try to connect the above database from Java end, I am getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Bad connection URL
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:280)
    ... 139 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Bad connection URL
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCMsgFactory.createException(UniJDBCMsgFactory.java:109)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver.connect(UniJDBCDriver.java:116)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:162)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    ... 140 more
```

Can anyone please tell what's wrong here?

Comment: @almasshaikh how is a link to the derby documentation relevant for DB2?

Comment: try connecting to that URL from a SQL client like SQuirreL (can't remember the IBM tool off the top of my head). This error means that the URL is incorrect. find a URL/DB name/ username/PW combo that works and then plug it into your XML.

Comment: Ahh didn't meant that! it should be of form jdbc:as400://HOST/DATABASE; as per the driver that OP specified but as tag says db2, OP should use "com.ibm.db2.jdbc.app.DB2Driver" as driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using AS400JDBCDriver, so your jdbc url should be something like:

```
jdbc:as400://123.43.133.257/XYZ
```

instead of

```
jdbc:db2://123.43.133.257/XYZ
```